# Make a .htaccess priority over a folder

Tags: .htaccess

This is my root folder :

- **index.php**
- **myfolder** (which contains other files, and a htaccess containing "*deny from all*").

When I access to http://www.domain.com/myfolder, I want to rewrite it to http://www.domain.com/Myfolder, but it seems that **it enters in the folder before the RewriteRule** (I have a 401).

Here is my .htaccess

```
# Charset
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

# URL Rewriting
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /myfolder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Myfolder [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?nav=$1 [L,QSA]
```

What's wrong with this ? Thank you !

Comment: what you trying to do is not achievable in case-insensitive OSs!

Comment: There's not [NC] flag, so my rule is case-sensitive, no ?

Comment: do you have an htaccess file in myfolder?

Comment: Yes, with `deny from all`, but the .htaccess in root should be executed first, isn't it ?

Comment: No, `[NC]` flag is for matching the rules,for example assume this is your request URI: `/HKH`,And your rewrite rule `RewriteRule ^/?hkh$  index.php?do=yes   [NC]`, Then your RegExp matches request URI and it will rewrite it, if you don't put `[NC]` flag, it will skip the rule and search document root for a directory named `HKH`!

Comment: Is there any reason that you don't use something else other than `/Myfolder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... in fact, there was another .htaccess file in a folder above this folder. Sorry :(